# Add class to elements for values of attribute with Backbone.ModelBinder

Tags: backbone.js, model-binding, marionette, model-binders

I'm using Backbone.ModelBinder in a Backbone.js Marionette project. I've a scenario which I can't work out how to use ModelBinder to automatically update my model/UI.

My model has a 'status' string attribute, with multiple states. In this example I'll show the code for two: 'soon', 'someday'

In my UI I have a list on which I use click events to set the model status, and update classes to highlight the relevant link in the UI.

```
<dd id="status-soon"><a>Soon</a></dd>
<dd id="status-someday" class="active"><a>Someday</a></dd>

events: {
    'click #status-soon': 'setStatusSoon',
    'click #status-someday': 'setStatusSomeday'
},
setStatusSoon: function () {
    this.model.set('status', 'soon');
    this.$el.find('.status dd').removeClass('active');
    this.$el.find('#status-soon').addClass('active');
},
... etc
```

It feels like I doing this a long-winded and clunky way! The code bloat increases with the number of states I need to support. What's the best way of achieving the same outcome with ModelBinder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably simplify things with a data attribute, something like this:

```
<dd data-status="soon" class="set-status"><a>Soon</a></dd>
<dd data-status="someday" class="set-status active"><a>Someday</a></dd>
```

and then:

```
events: {
    'click .set-status': 'setStatus'
},
setStatus: function(ev) {
    var $target = $(ev.target);
    var status  = $target.data('status');
    this.model.set('status', status);
    this.$el.find('.status dd.set-status').removeClass('active');
    $target.addClass('active');
}
```

You might not need the `set-status` class, just keying things on the `<dd>`s might be sufficient; I prefer separating my event handling from the nitty gritty element details though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is going to be pretty difficult to do exactly what you want with `ModelBinder`. The main reason being that `ModelBinder` wants to provide the same value for all elements that are part of a single selector. So doing this with `ModelBinder`, while possible, is going to be pretty verbose as well.

The cleanup offered by mu is likely to be better than trying to use `ModelBinder`. 1) because you need a click handler to do the `this.model.set` no matter what and 2) you would need individual bindings for `ModelBinder` because the converter function is called once for a single selector and then the value is set on all matching elements (rather than looping through each one).

But if you do want to try and do something with `ModelBinder` it would look something like this:

```
  onRender : function () {
    var converter = function (direction, value) { 
      return (value == "soon" ? "active" : "");
    };
    var bindings = {
      status : {selector : "#status-soon", elAttribute : "class", converter : converter}
    };
    this.modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el, bindings);
  }
```

This would do what you want. Of course the down side as I said above is that you will need multiple selector bindings. You could generalize the converter using `this.boundEls[0]` but you will still need the separate bindings for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to access to the bound element, it is possible to declare 'html' as elAttrbute, modify the element and return its html with converter function:

```
onRender : function () {
  var converter = function (direction, value, attribute, model, els) {
    return $(els[0]).toggleClass('active', value === 'soon').html();
  };
  var bindings = {
    status : {
      selector : "#status-soon", 
      elAttribute : "html", 
      converter : converter
    }
  };
  this.modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el, bindings);
}
```